# using npm scripts to Inject *.js and *.css into index.html

Tags: npm, inject, script-tag

I´m looking into switch from gulp/grunt to only use npm scripts.
But I cant really solve how to get *.js and *.css from a given path and add it to the index.html file.

must I add it thru a "index.js" file or can I do something like...

```
"scripts": {
 "inject": "inject src/app/*.js",
},
```

and then it will add it in my index.html where I have specified it like...

```
/* inject:js */
```

Comment: Is there really no one with an answer to this? :/

Comment: This looks promising https://www.npmjs.com/package/postbuild

Comment: Indeed!.. will take a look at it!

Comment: I used it over the weekend in a project and it worked well. Keep in mind This module was written in ES6 and requires node >= 4.0.0.

Answer (score 4):

The suggestion by Chris Traveis worked out pretty nice.
So the answer to my problem was solved using https://www.npmjs.com/package/postbuild

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/htmlparser2 parser is a powerful alternative that will allow any tag to be injected(instead of only JS and CSS).

Answer (score 1):

There were no answers in the last 3 months on this popular topic, probably because there are wrong assumptions in the question. Distilling your question,

> ...how to get *.js and *.css from a given path and add it to the index.html file

To be short, *do it manually*. Use a good npm boilerplate such as [npm-build-boilerplate](https://github.com/damonbauer/npm-build-boilerplate) and add the compiled JS and CSS files *manually* into your HTML.

> ... must I add it thru a "index.js" file, or <2nd option>

No. Add the files manually. Let me elaborate more.

With npm scripts you construct a pipeline and you know where your uglified JS files and compiled SCSS files are rendered. Yes, I have `"main": "index.js",` row in my `package.json`, but there's no "index.js" in my project at all. I get npm scripts to crunch files in various folders, to output them into other folders and I manually add end CSS and JS files into HTML templates (in my case, static [Hugo](https://gohugo.io/) website's templates).

I see one case where "dynamism" in the HTML is needed — when you want to bust cache and add the unique strings to the end-point CSS/JS file names. However, then you might want to consider scripts that count *MD5 hash* of the files' contents, because if you run the build multiple times and your existing CSS or JS files haven't changed, you want to *keep* the old file names. Visitors might have cached them (and think about CDN too). In this sense, npm `postbuild` script mentioned in the comments above is inferior because it just uses "version" counter. Look for alternatives to npm `postbuild` to bust caches.